# How to assign fixed data to database by ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby on rails, we usually assign data in model by console. 
like `@model = Model.attribute (data)`. Like `@user = User.create("John")`

My question is, if I want to have the data fixed, can I do it through model or controller? SO that if I want to change the detail, I do not have to check and find in console.

For example, I need 5 users and 5 users only, so I set `user_id = 1` is John `user_id = 2` is David...etc in model. Can I do that? How?

Answer (score 7):

You can create "fixed" data by [seeding data](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) via the `seeds.rb` file in your Rails application.

Let's suppose you want to create a user with specific data. Go into your app's `db` directory and open `seeds.rb` where you can add code that writes entries in your database.

```
User.create(    email: 'patron@patron.com',
                system_id: 2,
                subdomain: 'foo',
                external_id: '',
                first_name: 'Joe',
                last_name: 'Patron',
                phone_number: '213 555 1212',
                role: 'default',
                user_status_id: 1,
                password: 'password',
                password_confirmation: 'password',
                terms_accepted_at: datetime,
                created_at: datetime,
                updated_at: datetime)
```

You can see that you're calling the `create` method from whatever model you're working with and passing along all required parameters -- in other words, you're just using Ruby to build objects.

Once you have all your objects created, remember to run `rake db:seed` any time you reset your database in order to run the `seeds.rb` file to populate your database.